# creating nested tables in python tabulate

Tags: python-3.x, latex

I want to create a LaTeX table as follows in python:

```
duck    small    dog    small
        medium          medium
        large           large
```

how would I do that?

The list I have looks like:

```
lis=['dog',['small','medium','large],'duck',['small','medium','large']]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out.

The idea is not to treat this as nested tables but as one table. In this case a table with 4 columns, so you reformat your list as:

```
lis=[('dog','small','duck','small'),('','medium','','medium'),('','large','','large)]
```

then use the tabulate package:

```
from tabulate import tabulate
print(tabulate(lis))
```

voila:

```
---  ------  ----  ------
dog  small   duck  small
     medium        medium
     large         large
---  ------  ----  ------
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply combine the second column into one long string with newlines:

```
from tabulate import tabulate
table = []
table.append(["dog", "\n".join(["small", "medium", "large"])])
table.append(["fish", "\n".join(["wet", "dry", "happy", "sad"])])
table.append(["kangaroo", "\n".join(["depressed", "joyful"])])
print(tabulate(table, ["animal", "categories"], "grid"))
```

output:

```
+----------+--------------+
| animal   | categories   |
+==========+==============+
| dog      | small        |
|          | medium       |
|          | large        |
+----------+--------------+
| fish     | wet          |
|          | dry          |
|          | happy        |
|          | sad          |
+----------+--------------+
| kangaroo | depressed    |
|          | joyful       |
+----------+--------------+
```